# Copy excel table to outlook mail and keep the format

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am using VBA to send emails of a range of cells within excel. The size of the table goes haywire and all the text being wrap up when I copy over to outlook.

I would want to keep the same format and size of my table, and I tried to copy as picture but the picture becomes very small. It's from `A1:AP98`.

Anyone could help? I am using Microsoft office 2010

below is the code I have

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.Display

    olMail.To = "xxxx@xxxx.com"
    olMail.Subject = "Subject Line"
    olMail.HTMLBody = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Welcome to My World" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            RangetoHTML(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Ap90")) & _
           "Thank you for your cooperation." & "<br>" & olMail.HTMLBody
'    olMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: I am almost certain its the way you (don't) use html coding in your `.htmlBody`. replace vbNewLine with `<p>` and / or `<br>` statements. It's also a very big range (assuming the column size isn't uber-tiny).

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste it as an HTML object.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: works flawlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by breaking into parts.

First you will need to extract the data you need to a new worksheet. You can delete the worksheet later.

If you wish to copy the format as well, you can use 
 something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copy").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`. You might need `xlPasteFormats`, `xlPasteColumnWidths` & `xlPasteValues`.

To create new worksheet: `Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = "worksheetName"`

**MailEnvelop Example**

```
Sub sendEmail()

ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copy").MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = "This is the email message"
  .Item.To = "abc@domain.com"
  .Item.Subject = "Subject"
  .Item.Send

End With

ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

'Delete the the worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copy").Delete

End Sub
```

Read here for some good guidelines: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm