# Determine the range of a Dynamic Pivot Table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a macro that creates an email. The email's body is a fixed selected Range.

I want to change this because when someone receives the email there are blank lines after the body, which makes sense because the range is too large, and will include blank lines.

The range too large because the first part of the Sheet in Excel is "Hi, xyz here is the pivot table below....." then it will show a pivot table.

I don't know how big the pivot table will be, so I chose a number like 60, so it catches everything. The range looks something like `sheets("sheet1").range("A2:G60")`.

Is there is a way to make something like `RNG=sheets("sheet1").range("a2" & "pivottable1")`.

Comment: Take a look at [this description](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) of the different defined ranges already baked in to the `PivotTable` object. You are likely to want the `pt.TableRange1` reference, but don't use the `Select` part. Using `pt.TableRange1` is already a `Range`, so you can get the `.Address` or `.Rows.Count` or any other `Range` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLBody, instead body, please post your code to try it

check this
[Copy excel table to outlook mail and keep the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574223/copy-excel-table-to-outlook-mail-and-keep-the-format)

Comment: Hi Miguel, sorry... I do use HTML, but it still has blank lines. and makes the email super long.